# Android Navigation Drawer ListView Headers

Tags: android, android-listview, header, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I've made a navigation drawer in my app. Inside my navigation drawer is a `ListView`. It's a simple list view with text items. The Gmail android app has a `ListView` with headers.

[image: gmail app navigation drawer]
<sub>(source: [phonedog.com](http://r.phonedog.com/shared/images/2013/5/177720-newgmailappleak.jpg))</sub>

As you can see, the words: INBOX, RECENT LABELS, ALL LABELS are headers. I would like to implement exactly those type of headers into my app. Is this feature an inbuilt android thing or do I have to create something custom. If yes then how.

Let me know if you need any more info.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I found this great tutorial for Titles in Nav drawer: http://www.michenux.net/android-navigation-drawer-748.html

Comment: Umm, thanks but I used the developer.android.com/ method to create my nav drawer. So, isn't there a more simpler solution you can provide?

Comment: @ADeveloper: you can make new header layout that contains textview and underline as displayed in your image and then inflate it into your adapter's `getView()` method at specific position like for position 0, 3, 5 for above image.

Comment: Thank you. I did roughly the same thing. Although it would be nice if you provided the code through a legitimate answer.